# Windows Live Outlook embedded in frame

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

Im developing a website for a school where teachers can log in using their Windows Live account, this works, however, I'm trying to make email accessible through this website. I've tried using an iFrame with the src set to the online Outlook URL https://db3prd0602.outlook.com/owa/. I haven't come across a help page by Microsoft concerning this, neither am I aware if they allow access to their pages from a different domain.

This doesn't give me the results I've been trying to get, for some reason this frame will redirect the document to it's location, in this case: https://db3prd0602.outlook.com/owa/.

Any ideas?
Thanks, Rik

Comment: Looks like the application protects itself being framed. Try with javascript switched of and tell if the issue is still there (this is not a fix!).

Comment: It's probably got javascript that breaks it out of frames. Unless you're able to read the contents of the page and strip out the offending js (or edit the source on the server) you're out of luck.

Comment: It actually has got. And it has got a redirect on `<noscript>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems an interesting question.

First, I tried the same and THEN look into the frame's source. Firefox considered it as an about:blank.

Then, looking at the source, I saw that with no script on, it redirects. It is looking like: `<noscript><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.live.com/jsDisabled.srf?mkt=HU-HU&lc=1038"/>[Some text localized on every language]</noscript>` So it does not work, either.

Also, this should be noted: `<script type="text/javascript">if (top != self){ try{ top.location.replace(self.location.href);}catch (e){ }}else{ document.write(unescape('%3C%73') + 'tyle type="text/css">body{display:block !important;}</style>');}</script></head>` This seems to be doing the IFrame replacement as it does that if top location (so your url) isn't equal to self (page url), it tries to replace top URL and catch what happens. I don't really know if only this protects or something else, too, but this could be put into consideration.